# ClickOnce keeps prompting user to reinstall application

Tags: clickonce

We have just installed a new server hosting a ClickOnce application. Now when we launch the app on a client PC it asks us to install even though it's already installed. This only happens on the first load after the client PC has booted up, after that the app launches normally.

There are no start up scripts in place and users are all running Windows Defender Anti Virus.

Could it be domain policy or registry setting that was not copied over from the old server?